# Is there any way to read protractor.conf suites names into txt file?

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor.conf file which includes suites, for example:

```
suites: {
  login: '..PATH',
  register: '..PATH',
  logout: '..PATH'
}
```

I want to somehow get the names of the suites and make some use of them, for example putting them in txt file. So the result should be:

**test-names.txt**

```
login
register
logout
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done with nodejs.

For example, you have the `protractor.conf.js` file:

```
exports.config = {
  ...
  suites: {
    login: '..PATH',
    register: '..PATH',
    logout: '..PATH'
  },
  ...
}
```

Create a new javascript file(e.g. `writeSuiteNames.js`) or wrap this snippet of code in function and put it somewhere and invoke where you need it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { config: { suites } } = require('./protractor.conf.js')

fs.writeFile("./test-names.txt", `Suites: ${Object.keys(suites)}`, err => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);

  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Then run the `node writeSuiteNames.js` command.

The `test-names.txt` file was successfully created and containing the suite names:

> Suites: login,register,logout